# Regex replace multiple occurrences of characters with single

Tags: regex

I can replace multiple spaces with `.replaceAll" +", " ")` and multiple exclamation marks with `.replaceAll("!+", "!")` and of course multiple question marks with `.replaceAll("?+", "?")`....but how can I do it all with one regex?

I can do `[ !?]+` and replace with `$1` but that doesn't work since it replaces it exactly as it was. How can I get it to replace with a SINGLE occurrence of the character matched?

Comment: Replace `([ !?])\1+` with `$1`. See: https://regex101.com/r/0D6uvn/1

Comment: @41686d6564 It doesn't seem to work properly. If there's a space before or after the exclamation marks it deletes the whole thing. https://regex101.com/r/ist838/1/

Comment: You were too quick to test it before I edited the comment :). Please use the updated pattern.

Comment: @41686d6564 OK yeah your updated pattern works. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: It's already answered in the linked post. Just choose "Yes" in the prompt you get above the question.